# Old Flatpak version in Focal repo: no Chromium for me?

Tags: 20.04, chromium, flatpak

Tried to install flatpak Chromium, to no avail:

```
 5. [✗] org.chromium.Chromium                     stable           i            flathub           < 102.8 MB

Error: org.chromium.Chromium needs a later flatpak version
error: Failed to install org.chromium.Chromium: app/org.chromium.Chromium/x86_64/stable needs a later flatpak version (1.8.2)
```

Flatpak 1.8.2 is available starting with Groovy:

```
$ rmadison flatpak
 flatpak | 0.11.3-3               | bionic/universe          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 flatpak | 1.0.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 | bionic-security/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 flatpak | 1.0.9-0ubuntu0.1       | bionic-updates/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 flatpak | 1.6.3-1                | focal/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 flatpak | 1.6.5-0ubuntu0.1       | focal-updates/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 flatpak | 1.8.2-1                | groovy/universe          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 flatpak | 1.8.4-1                | hirsute/universe         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

I guess I could remove the official Flatpak and use some PPA instead, but it would pretty much undermine the whole idea of getting your software from a trusted source. Snap Chromium is painfully slow on my system for some reason. (As well as snap Firefox.) So, any options left?

Comment: TIL that in Focal, unlike in Xenial, `chromium-browser` is just an alias to the snap version. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/chromium-browser vs https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/chromium-browser Good to know.

Comment: In case anybody is considering asking the Flatpak Chromium maintainers to lower the minimum Flatpak version required, [Chromium depends on bug fixes and features added in Flatpak 1.8.2](https://github.com/flathub/org.chromium.Chromium/issues/62#issuecomment-773508532).

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to fear.

Official FlatPak setup guide https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/ lists [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

So you have to open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.chromium.Chromium
```

Note: I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS, so the PPA is also needed for me.

Comment: Sadly, this solution is not scalable; I upgraded from Bionic to Focal exactly to move away from stale repos, manually added PPAs and even more manual package downloads. Worked for a whole 2 months! Maybe I should switch to interim releases.

Comment: Sounds very opinion-based. I have recently switched from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. And I see that number of needed PPAs seriously reduced. For now I have only 14 PPAs added. Interim releases will force you to run frequent upgrades (i.e. 20.10 → 21.04 → 21.10 → 22.04 LTS). Using LTS is better and safer. I would recommend to stay with 20.04 LTS and add only one FlatPak PPA.

Comment: Okay, I'm somewhat lost here: did you add only one FlatPak PPA and it was enough, or did you still have to add 13 more PPAs to get up-to-date software?

Comment: To get Chromium from FlatPak I have added only [one PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ealexlarsson/+archive/ubuntu/flatpak) to the fresh 20.04 LTS VM. All other context is not related to Chromium and to this question. I wrote it to tell you about LTS systems and my personal experience with them.

Comment: So, the conclusion is that Flatpak does not help us avoid the PPA sprawl issue on LTS anyway. Thanks for sharing your experience, I'll definitely take it into consideration.

Comment: take the snap version : sudo snap install chromium